# Results returned wrong results for C++ in VSCcode

Tags: c++

I was trying to learn C++ on my own, and there's a weird result from my first testing with the code in VSCode.

My testing code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y, sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        y += 2;
        sum = x + y;
        cout << "The sum is = " << sum << "\n";

        if (x == 5)
        {
            break;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to give out the results as:

[image]

Above is the correct result which I tested on other online compilers.
While in VSCode, I get the below result instead in the terminal after I run the code:

[image]

Is it just me or VSCode is not suitable or are there things I should configure/set up for C++? Thanks

Comment: `y += 2;` what is the value of `y` before this line is executed, and what is it afterwards? Spoiler: `y` is uninitialized, incrementing it is undefined behavior

Comment: common rule of thumb is to always initialize variables as soon as you declare it ( never declare a variable without initializing it(. And this is much easier to follow if you also stick to another rule: Declare only one variable per line.

Comment: `int x, y, sum = 0;` is the same as `int x;   int  y; int sum = 0;` it should be `int y =0; sum = 0;` (you are not using `x`, there is a second `x` in the loop, but its a distinct separate variable)

Comment: First of all, VSC has nothing to do with the result, as it's just a text editor. Only your compiler choice matters here. Second, you should enable compiler warnings (assuming the compiler is GCC, that would be something like `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`). The compiler should've warned you about the uninitialized variable.

Comment: Good example of why it's not very *practical* to learn C++ on your own. Buy a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282). You will find as you continue learning C++ that when something doesn't work as expected, it is almost always your error or lack of understanding that is to blame, rather than the tools you are using. C++ is complex and for most beginners non-intuitive.

Comment: [Results using clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TbEPzvqs6).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are not initialising the value of y to zero in your code.

```
int x,y=0,sum=0;
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Removing the unused variable `x` would be a good idea too